# How to Add Css style sheet on DevExpress Gridview?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, devexpress

i have big problem about CssFilePath property in ASPXGridView .

also used Theme Deployer. i created ASPXGRidView that is goog in 9.3.4 version not problem is occured but i upgrated my system to 2010.2 version (Last version) but GridView CssFilePath not working my GridView looks html table.

How can i solve it :
[image]

i converted my project devexpress 9.3.4 to 2010.2 but My Working gridView look like this:TEST.ASCX has got a DevExpress GridView.

[image]

```
  <Styles CssFilePath="../../App_Themes/Aqua/GridView/styles.css" CssPostfix="Aqua"></Styles>
```

i see asp.net design mode Aqua mode every thing ok. But press f5 my Gridview look above! how can i see aqua style...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the theme dll in your project (DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v10.2.dll), also you noted that you updated to 10.2, make sure you don't have straggler dlls from 9.3.4 in your bin directory.  Maybe even delete the temp files in your ASP.NET temp folder (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files).